# Create start XML manually

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, xmlwriter

I want to create `XML` file so i am using this way:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
                  {
                      Indent = true,
                      Encoding = Encoding.Unicode
                  };

string xmlPath = @"c:\file.xml";
XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(xmlPath, settings);
xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument(false);
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="no"?>
<cp>
  <user>NA</user>
  <password>NA</password>
</cu>
```

But i want this start XML will be `Upper case`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
```

So i try to create this start manually:

```
 XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
                   {
                        Indent = true,
                        Encoding = Encoding.Unicode
                   };

string xmlPath = @"c:\file.xml";
XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(xmlPath, settings);
xmlWriter.WriteRaw("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\" standalone=\"no\"?>\r\n");
```

But the result was that i received the start twice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
```

Comment: *Why* do you want the encoding to be upper case? Case doesn't matter. Hard-coding the encoding just *begs* for bugs, eg if you save the file as the default UTF-8.

Comment: BTW the default encoding used by XmlWriter is UTF-8. Why change it to UTF-16?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following line before you start writing the xml.
That is,

```
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
string xmlPath = @"c:\file.xml";
XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(xmlPath, settings);
xmlWriter.WriteRaw("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\" standalone=\"no\"?>\r\n");
```

This way your xml will be created not with the default declaration, but with the one that you are adding exclusively.